# How to display series lable same on point data in primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

I want to display series lable in each point data same as point lable in bar chart in primefaces. It can do by tool tips but I want to display in chart by default. Thanks.

Comment: your question is not clear, can you put some code that you tryed to do?

Comment: can you post some code or image, what you want.